# Can I continue exporting data despite the snapshot too old error?

Tags: oracle, expdp

I am exporting a schema from Oracle production database to create a new, test database.

Unfortunately, I received the error **ORA-01555: snapshot too old**

Despite the error, export still in progress .dmp file is growing.

I don't care about the consistency and quality of the data - The application team will test some tested migrations.

**Can I continue and be able to import this data into my new test database?**

Comment: Unless you are taking a consistent export (where all tables are exported with the same `as of scn/timestamp`) this error will only be effecting the table it errored against. You can try another export with just this table and see if it runs fast enough a second time - general advice would be to run it during a quiet period so that less undo will be required. Of course, you can also use backups or disk snapshots for this sort of requirement

Answer (score -1):

See Oracle Support [Doc ID 452341.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=13242433193347&parent=EXTERNAL_SEARCH&sourceId=PROBLEM&id=452341.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=107c1tpoxx_4). This is most likely caused by corrupted LOB files and will require a physical recovery from backup. The Doc has specific steps to verify which LOBs are affected and correct the issue.